# Windows 7 Language Pack does not show the option to install English version

Tags: windows-7, language-pack

At my work place all PC's are running Windows 7 Enterprise edition in German Language. I was trying to change the language by installing english language pack but it is not working.

After going to windows optional updates, I see the option to install language packs but strangely it does not show the english option:

[image]

I have tried everything, but it seems there is something missing. Can you please suggest what it is that I need to do to be able to install english langauge pack??

Comment: Are you sure its not already installed?

Comment: Are you certain it isn't already installed?  EDIT: Doh, beaten to the punch.

Comment: yes but how can i check? i check the installed software / windows components and don't see anything related to langauge pack there? Plus since it is german so finding the right section is a hell of a problem as well.

Comment: If you don't even know how to check how can you be certain its not already installed?

Comment: @Ramhound if he knows how to obtain the info about this then why he come here to ask the question. If you can't help him why are you just commenting leave it as it as.

Comment: @avirk - I am just asking a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note**: The [English MUI pack for Windows 7](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/updt/2009/08/windows6.1-kb972813-x86-en-us_22ee3397a02372681b375ddabf6ffa33662fd500.exe) can be obtained from Windows Update directly.

### Switching already installed MUI packs

This is the German **Region and Language** (Region und Sprache) dialog. Here you can switch between installed display languages:

[image]

---

### If you want to remove the MUI pack

Please note, removing the language pack should not be required to be able to *switch* to the English language. However, if you want to remove the pack, this is how:

1. Open the **Region and Language** control panel and click **Install/uninstall languages...**

   [image]
2. Click **Uninstall display languages**

   [image]
3. Uninstall the German language pack (if it is installed):

   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much, infact as already mentioned it seems English Pack was alredy installed. When i went to this option you mentioend, i could see this: http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/5517/lanpack2.png
So i selected english, and it required a logout and now with my user account i see everything in english. Thank you so much

Comment: @Johny if you wants to thanks him properly just mark the post as solve by click on the check mark.